# Why is the value of my input this [object HTMLInputElement]?

Tags: jquery, input

I can't figure out why it is not printing out the value of my `<input type="text">`?

```
$('#x').click(function() {
    var firstname = $("#student_firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#student_lastname").val();

    $("ul").after('<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px; border:2px solid black" name="c[]"><strong>First Name</strong> ' + student_firstname + ', <strong>Last Name</strong> ' + student_lastname + '</li>');
 });
```

Comment: Because you are selecting a html tag within the DOM. You should post infos on your DOM if you want some more helpl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your issue is because your variables are named `firstname` and `lastname`, not `student_firstname` and `student_lastname`. When you use those names, Javascript retrieves the elements with those `id` attributes and returns them. In this case they are HTMLInputElements, and when coerced to strings give the output you see.

Also note that you should use `append()` not `after()` to add the `li` to the `ul`.

Here's a working version of your code:

```js
$('#x').click(function() {
  var firstname = $("#student_firstname").val();
  var lastname = $("#student_lastname").val();

  $("ul").append('<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px; border:2px solid black" name="c[]"><strong>First Name</strong> ' + firstname + ', <strong>Last Name</strong > ' + lastname + ' </li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="student_firstname" value="fn" />
<input type="text" id="student_lastname" value="fn" />
<button id="x">Click me</button>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)